# ssrs report not render but Pdf Export successfully

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

i am using ssrs report ,and i have some problem in that when i try to open report using report viewer report showing a blank page but report export to pdf working fine blank render report also  Export successfully and print also it is working fine 
but the problem is in report viewer report not render and it is showing blank page if i try to find something or some key word if i enter to find that all report are render properly .

in report server if i try to open the report it is showing blank.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a browser problem, the reports that i create on ssrs 2008 r2 only seem to render correctly on Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your parameters, If any are unhidden or set to prompt user then SSRS won't render direct to PDF

Answer (score 0):

If any of your parameters having more than 1000 available values this problem may occur.
Please have a look on this question and answer:
[Report is not loading when using parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117444/report-is-not-loading-when-using-parameters)