# Report is not loading when using parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

I have created a ssrs report and uploaded it in reportserver which is working fine. Then I have added 4 parameters to the same report. 
It works fine in my local machine,But not working when uploaded to report server. Is it because of any permission issues?

Comment: Delete the report from the server and re-upload it and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yes. Tried that. But unfortunately not working

Comment: which browser are you working with ? if you didn't use internet explorer try to use it and run it as administrator

Comment: define "not working".   Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Report viewer itself not loading even I have admin role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was because one of my reports was having more than 1000 values. So I have made the following changes in web.config of the Reports server and it is working fine.

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="10000" />
```

Comment: Was this > 1000 values in a dropdown parameter menu or the actual result data from the report itself?